# Почему не вызывает метод при компиляции?

Tags: java, функции

```
public class Start {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SanyaArray program = new SanyaArray();//приветствие,создать массив?
    int StartMenuResult = program.startMenu();//Результат первого действия.
    program.arraySize(StartMenuResult);//Запрос размера массива.

}
```

}

---

```
public class SanyaArray implements Functions {

private ArrayList<Integer> array;

@Override
public int startMenu() {
    System.out.println("Добрый день! \nСделайте выбор:\n1)Cоздать список.\n2)Выход");
  int choice = getInteger(4); // ***ЭТА СТРОКА НЕ РАБОТАЕТ,КОД ПРОСТО ИДЕТ ДАЛЬШЕ***

    if (choice == 1) {return choice;}
    if (choice==2) {System.exit(0);}

    return choice;
}
```

---

```
@Override
public int getInteger(int option) {//метод для получения чисел.
    // В параметрах метода нужно передать нужный вариант операции.
    // 1) Введите число от 1 до 7
    // 2) Целое позитивное число, которое больше или равно 0.
    // 3) Любое целое число.
    // 4) Целое позитивное число, которое больше 0.
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int element = 0;

    if (option == 1) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                element = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

                if (element > 0 && element < 8) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Введите число от 1 до 7.");
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка ввода,введите целое число!");

            }
        }
    }
    if (option == 2) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                element = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

                if (element >= 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Введите позитивное число,которое больше или равно 0!");
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка ввода,введите целое число!");

            }
        }
    }
    if (option == 3) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                element = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка ввода,введите целое число!");

            }
        }
    }
    if (option == 2) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                element = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

                if (element > 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Введите позитивное число,которое больше 0!");
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка ввода,введите целое число!");

            }
        }
    }
    return element;

}
```

Comment: А почему какой-то код компилируемой программы должен вызываться при ее компиляции?

Comment: кто такой `getInteger` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил код этого метода.Глянь.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Что ты имеешь ввиду?

Comment: `ЭТА СТРОКА НЕ РАБОТАЕТ,КОД ПРОСТО ИДЕТ ДАЛЬШЕ` - логично, ведь в `getInteger` нет условий для числа `4`

Comment: @АлександрБезбородов ровно то, что и написал. Почему вы пишете "не вызывает метод при компиляции", но не сообщаете, почему метод при компиляции должен быть вызван?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский оу,вот это затуууууп. сорре.Не выспался:) хорошего дня.

Comment: @АлександрБезбородов бывает....Закрою-ка я вопрос с дубликатом на полезный. Советую взглянуть